# How do I check an array for duplicates?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I've got an array A. I'd like to check if it contains duplicate values. How would I do so?

Comment: "marked as duplicate" well this is pretty meta considering the question.

Comment: "How do I check an array for duplicates?" is not quite the same question as "How to find and return a duplicate value in an array?".  This question is asking how to determine the uniqueness of the array, whereas the other is asking how to pull duplicate values out of the array.  I don't think it should be marked as duplicate -- but the other question is similar, and should be linked in a comment.

Comment: But the irony is rich, isn't it?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Just call `uniq` on it (which returns a new array without duplicates) and see whether the `uniq`ed array has less elements than the original:

```
if a.uniq.length == a.length
  puts "a does not contain duplicates"
else
  puts "a does contain duplicates"
end
```

Note that the objects in the array need to respond to `hash` and `eql?` in a meaningful for `uniq` to work properly.

Comment: Additionally, `uniq!` will return `nil` if no duplicates were found, altering self to remove duplicates.  There are a lot of array methods available: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html

Comment: Of course, if they don't respond to `eql?` in a meaningful way, then what does "duplicate" even **mean**? And once you've defined `eql?`, `hash` should be consistent with it.

Comment: @Karl: That two elements in the array are `==` to each other?

Comment: @sepp2k Out of curiosity, why do you have `a.uniq.length == a.length` instead of just `a.uniq == a`?

Comment: @sepp2k: Yes... and isn't that exactly what `eql?` is for? :/

Comment: @phoffer, checking size is faster.

Comment: @Karl: I'm not sure what you mean by that. My point is there are classes which override `==`, but not `eql?` or `hash` (like `Array` and `Hash` in ruby 1.8.6 for example), and for those `uniq` would yield surprising results while a more primitive solution using `==` would not.

Comment: @sepp2k Just looked up the difference between `==` and `eql?` in Ruby. Don't really see what's going on here - why would you ever implement `eql?` as something other than a type-check followed by an `==` check? Will Ruby not fall back to `==` when `eql?` isn't specifically provided? That kinda sucks...

Comment: @Karl: `Object#eql?` will call `equal?`, which checks for reference equality and should not be overridden. This corresponds with `Object#hash`, which returns the object's `object_id`. If `Object#eql?` called `==` then overriding `==` without overriding `hash` would break the same way that overriding `eql?` without `hash` does. The way it is now, `eql?` and `hash` are still in sync if you only override `==`, they just don't act the way one might expect (but that's still better than being totally broken). The problem is that ruby can't automatically define `hash` to be in sync with `==`.

Comment: @sepp2k `eql?` calls `equal?` ? That's just supposed to be an optimization, right? Irritating if that sort of optimization causes a headache. :( I understand that `eql?` is supposed to compare both value and type, so it shouldn't particularly care about identity - identity implies (value and type), sure, but just testing value and type separately would be fine anyway, surely?

Comment: @Karl: How would you propose testing for the value? Calling `==`? As I said that would break if you don't override `hash`. Comparing every instance variable (and likewise hashing every instance variable in `hash`)? That might work in some/most cases, but does not always lead to the wanted behavior either (of course you could still override in the cases where it doesn't...). It should be noted that both `eql?` and `==` default to calling `equal?`, so generally objects don't have a notion of value other than their object_id unless you define one.

Comment: @sepp2k so... let me see if you have this straight. If you implement `==`, you need to implement `hash`. If you need to implement `eql?`, you need to implement `hash` as well. `eql?` is supposed to be equivalent to checking a type in addition to whatever `==` does. So what exactly is accomplished by offering the ability to override either or both of `==` and `eql?`. Why does Ruby make the distinction?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351390/how-do-i-check-an-array-for-duplicates .  One answer says that == tests for equality and eql? tests for equality and same type.

Comment: @Wayne: But it doesn't return true right away if the sizes don't differ (which would be stupid of course).

Comment: @sepp2k, How dumb of me!  I'll kill that comment.

Comment: @Nakilon Thanks, I'd never thought of that but it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Wayne Conrad: "== tests for equality and eql? tests for equality and same type" ... that doesn't say anything I haven't already acknowledged several times now. My point: isn't testing for same type built-in? Why would you need to write a wrapper to combine the two tests, and, worse, re-write it for every class? For a Pythonista this is very confusing... we only have `==` (implemented using \_\_eq\_\_) and `is` (equivalent to `equal?`).

Answer (score 39):

In order to find the duplicated elements, I use this approach (with Ruby 1.9.3):

```
array = [1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5]
=> [1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5]
dup = array.select{|element| array.count(element) > 1 }
=> [1, 1, 5, 5, 5]
dup.uniq
=> [1, 5]
```

Comment: select { array.count } is a nested loop, you're doing an O(n^2) complex algorithm for something which can be done in O(n).

Comment: You're right, to solve this Skizit's question we can use in O(n); but in order to find out which elements are duplicated an O(n^2) algo is the only way I can think of so far.

Comment: sort and remove consecutives for n log n

Comment: @apeiros where's your O(n) answer?

Comment: @alex88 I didn't provide one as others already did. For example sepp2k's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4351408/764342

Answer (score 9):

If you want to return the duplicates, you can do this:

```
dups = [1,1,1,2,2,3].group_by{|e| e}.keep_if{|_, e| e.length > 1}
# => {1=>[1, 1, 1], 2=>[2, 2]}
```

If you want just the values:

```
dups.keys
# => [1, 2]
```

If you want the number of duplicates:

```
dups.map{|k, v| {k => v.length}}
# => [{1=>3}, {2=>2}]
```

Comment: `.group_by{|e| e}` is equivalent to `.group_by(&:itself)`

Answer (score 5):

Might want to monkeypatch Array if using this more than once:

```
class Array
  def uniq?
    self.length == self.uniq.length
  end
end
```

Then:

```
irb(main):018:0> [1,2].uniq?
=> true
irb(main):019:0> [2,2].uniq?
=> false
```

Comment: I would avoid monkey patching to wrap a one-liner.

Comment: monkey patches do tend to bite

Comment: @sidewaysmilk why should this be avoided?  It seems like the ruby way: elegant, dynamic and dry.

Comment: One (main?) reason is that if you do it in code that ends up being used by others (gems), they pull in your monkeypatches, which can lead to unexpected behaviour. So I guess I should add a caveat that this should only be used in code you'll use yourself, and in a place that you can remember (a monkey_patch.rb file?), so you don't have to hunt too much for code that changes the default behaviour.